# Cual es la mejor manera que la app mande posicion gps cada 30 segundos

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, timer, backgroundworker

No soy especialista y soy nuevo. Probe alarma y me.genera errores en en j7 2016... leí que es porque demora más de ciertos segundos.la verdad es que no se como resolverlo.
La.idea es tomar la posición, que eso lo tengo resuelto, y mandarlo a un php, en la web (eso también resolvi) el tema es el.timer o la periodicidad. Que se ejecute aunque no esté activa la app...

Comment: Agrega lo que haz realizado! revisa [ask] edita tu pregunta y te aseguro obtendrás ayuda rápidamente, saludos.